# How can i bend the outline with css?

Tags: css

[image]

I am trying to create this outline effect using CSS. I am unable to think in the right direction and don't want to use any image for the bending.

So what's the best approach to do this?

Comment: CSS is not a graphics drawing tool.

Comment: Additionally, what is the content being "bent" around (image, html, etc.)? Are you trying to create a dynamic solution or a fixed shape?

Comment: @Rob hahaha... it can be

Comment: @William_Wilson : a dynamic solution as i can have more divs

Comment: @William_Wilson, it is a normal div with some content inside ( text ).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an idea that rely on some `box-shadow`, `border` and pseudo-element to create the link between elements:

```css
.out {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 30px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #fff inset, 0 0 0 50px lightblue inset;
  border: 2px dashed red;
  position: relative;
}

.out:not(:last-child)::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: -8px;
  top: calc(50% - 5px);
  width: 9px;
  height: 10px;
  border-top: 2px dashed red;
  border-bottom: 2px dashed red;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #fff inset, 0 0 0 50px lightblue inset;
}

.out:not(:last-child):before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: -40px;
  top: calc(50% - 1.5px);
  width: 60px;
  height: 5px;
  z-index: 3;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="out">
  </div>
  <div class="out">
  </div>
  <div class="out">
  </div>
  <div class="out">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, man, that's all I needed to get started.

Comment: I will select it as the answer in few minutes but I will wait for some other ideas also  :)

Comment: @Aslam of course ;) don't precipitate, more idea will comme for sure